Angular MongoDB Node.js Using Object.defineProperty The Value Not Being Added to Data
I'm trying to modify a property value in MongoDB collection. From the client side using Angular I have tried both Object.defineProperty  as well as ObjectdefineProperties neither one is adding the value.  I can see the the value added on the request but there is no value when I review it in the database.  I tried changing the writeable, enumerable and configurable between true and false nothing works.
This is what I trying to accomplish, when a size is chosen from client side via a radio button I  want to add size to  the product before it is inserted into the database.  According to documentation this is the way its done and Object.defineProperty does work on MongoDB. Of course this worked on my fake back in.  Am I missing something?
Code snippet below
My Service:
   addProductToCart(product:Products, _id:String, Valuesize:String):Observable<Product>{

      //This should add a size 
      Object.defineProperties(product,{
       size:{
       value: "s",  //I hard code a size in to see if I was indeed getting it
       writable: true

       }

     });

    alert("What is property" + product.size )

  return this.http.post<any>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts/addtocart' + _id, {product});

 }

I also tried these ways changing writable, enumerable and configurable
 Object.defineProperty(product, "size",{
  value: "M",
  //writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
 })



 Object.defineProperties(product,{
    size: {
    value: "S",
    writable: false,
    //enumerable: true,
    //configurable: true
  }

 });

/*Still the same result adding to request but the value does not 
  change on insert to db.*/
 
 /* I check my Schema everything is correct
  When used Object.defineProperties I was attempting to modify
  so database like this for example: Trying to add size value.*/

   {
  "productId": "1",
  "name": "Overalls",
  "size": "",
  "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
   and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's",
  "imageUrl": "http://localhost:4200/assets/overalls.png",
  "price": 250,
  "qty": 1
 }


 /*If I use Object.defineProperty to add a new property and value 
   interchanging write, enumerable and 
   configurable. No matter which I change I get the same 
   result*/

   {
  "productId": "1",
  "name": "Overalls",
  "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
   and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
   standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
   printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
   specimen book.",
  "imageUrl": "http://localhost:4200/assets/overalls.png",
  "price": 250,
  "qty": 1
}

      Object.defineProperty(product, "size",{
        value: "M",
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
     })

      
  I did trying taking out Observable as well.
  Any help in pointing me in the right direction will be greatly 
   appreciate.

